# After running "$ mysql -u root -p", it returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: mysql

In my local terminal, after running:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it returns:

```
bash: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory
```

Yes, I have installed everything as:

```
(envir) MBPganghinanban:ADB_nov20_2021 xxx$ brew services stop mysql
Stopping `mysql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
(envir) MBPganghinanban:ADB_nov20_2021 xxx$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS! 
(envir) MBPganghinanban:ADB_nov20_2021 xxx$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

The part I suspect is that I have executed this previously:

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql
```

In addition, it also returns "No such file or directory" if I run:

```
mysql
```

I am not sure of not being able to execute "mysql -u root -p" while being able to login to the server. Please help.

Comment: just **check** if `/usr/local/mysql` exists

Comment: Thanks! No, '/usr/local/mysql' does not exist. what should I do in order to execute "mysql -u root -p"?

Comment: Execute it from the correct location

Comment: you can also find a file a root by execute **find / -name mysql -perm -u=x -type f** . If you find the correct file you can execute it with the path or add the directory to the PATH env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the community. I have followed the instruction from Cid, meanwhile I have used:

```
which mysql
```

Hence, I found the path of my installation is at: /usr/local/bin/mysql
Then

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/mysql”
```

The problem is solved!

Comment: that shows me nothing but a empty response.